# Batch file check whether file modify date is newer than output

Tags: batch-file, time

I have a script which compresses all CSS and JS using YUICompressor before making a production version of the site. I got it working, but I'd like to speed it up by only compressing those files that are modified.

In other words, if the output file is newer than the input file, it should skip.

```
@echo off
set batch_path=%~p0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call:compress css styles\core\ ..\core\resources\styles\
call:compress js scripts\core\ ..\core\resources\scripts\

pause
goto:eof


:compress
for /r .\%~2 %%f in (*) do (
    set filename=%%f

    rem set output filename to correct directory and add .min before extension
    set output_filename=%%~pf
    set output_filename=!output_filename:%batch_path%%~2=!
    set output_filename=%~3!output_filename!%%~nf.min%%~xf

    echo. !filename! =^> !output_filename!

    rem --- check file modify times ---

    rem change \ into \\ for yuicompressor
    set filename=!filename:\=\\!
    set output_filename=!output_filename:\=\\!

    java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type %~1 -o "!output_filename!" "!filename!"
)
goto:eof
```

I find only complex solutions, how would I compare the file modify times and either proceed or skip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Comparing a modified file date with the current date in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349815/comparing-a-modified-file-date-with-the-current-date-in-a-batch-file)

```
for %%f in (%filename%) do set filedt=%%~tf
for %%f in (!output_filename!) do set outfiledt=%%~tf
if %filedt:~0, 10% LSS %outfiledt:~0, 10% DO SOMETHING
```

if filename is older than outfilename - do something.

Comment: Windows write the date in the local format, for me it’s `day`.`month`.`year` `time`. I expect this script won’t work at the turn of the month or year.