# How to compare today's date with a file's last modification date without regional settings influence?

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, command-line, regional-settings

It is possible to get the current date on a Windows system and the last modification date of a file, like thise:

- Current date : `date /T`
- Last modification date : ±`echo %~tI%` (where `%I` is the file within a `FOR` loop)

Both however depend on regional settings, so they need to be replaced by something else:

- Current date : `wmic os get localdatetime`
- Last modification date : ???

Does somebody know how to fill in the question marks?

Background information, the idea is to get a result like the following:

- Current date : 20170323115047.782000+060
- Last modification date : 20170323120513.0123

Chop off the first eight characters (in order to get the day)

- Current date : 20170323
- Last modification date : 20170323

This makes it possible to see that the file has indeed been modified today.
I want to avoid regional settings in order to be sure of the amount of characters I need to chop off.

Comment: Although `date /T` and `%%~tI` return the locale-dependent date formats, they can still be used for (non-)equality comparisons as the format are the same, given that you split off the time portion of `%%~tI` at the first _space_, and that the _space_ is not used as date separator (which is very unlikely)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For timestamp comparisons, you could use `forfiles` to find files modified today.  This solution is more graceful than chopping substrings off of WMI query results I think.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "file=notes.txt"

forfiles /d +0 /m "%file%" >NUL 2>NUL && (
    echo %file% was modified today.
) || (
    for %%I in ("%file%") do echo %%~I was last modified %%~tI
)
```

`forfiles /?` in a cmd console for more info.  The `forfiles` command exits 0 on match, 1 on no match, allowing the use of [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).  Also, [see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30620330/1683264).

Answer (score 4):

The following batch output it's own lastmodified datetime via wmic.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal
set File=%~f0
:: need to escape \ with another one \\
set File=%File:\=\\%
for /f %%a in (
    'wmic  DataFile where "Name='%File%'" get lastmodified   ^| findstr "^[0-9]" '
) do Echo File:%File% lastmodified:%%a
```

Sample output

```
> 12-16.cmd
File:Q:\\Test\\2017-03\\23\\12-16.cmd lastmodified:20170323123900.908030+060
```

Answer (score 4):

LotPings' script gives you the idea how to start but there's a little bit more on complete check. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
::change to the needed file or to the command line argument
set fileLoc=%~f0
set fileLoc=%fileLoc:\=\\%

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:value') do (
    for  /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%#") do set "%%a"
)

::echo %LocalDateTime%
set today=%LocalDateTime:~0,8%
echo today: %today%




for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('wmic  DataFile where "Name='%fileLoc%'" get lastmodified /format:Value ') do (

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%#") do set "%%a"
)

echo %lastmodified%
set lmodified=%lastmodified:~0,8%

if "%lmodified%" equ "%lmodified%" (
    echo modified today
) else (
    echo hasnt been modified today
)
endlocal
```

Here's substring is explained : https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

Comment: ++npocmaka, but where's your `setlocal`?  Its conspicuous exclusion is bothering my OCD.

Answer (score 4):

Rojo is correct that `FORFILES` can be used to list files that have been modified today. But it is S.L..O...W.....

`ROBOCOPY` is much faster :-)

The following will list recently modified files in the current directory.

```
robocopy . . /l /is /maxage:1 /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl /fp
```

You can specify a specific path if you want

```
robocopy "c:\your\path" "c:\your\path" /l /is /maxage:1 /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl /fp
```

You can add the `/S` to recursively search all child folders

```
robocopy "c:\your\path" "c:\your\path" /l /is /maxage:1 /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl /fp /s
```

Answer (score 2):

Although [`date /T`](http://ss64.com/nt/date.html)/[`%DATE%`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) and [`%%~tI`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) return the locale-dependent date formats, they can still be used for (non-)equality comparisons as the formats are the same, given that you split off the time portion of `%%~tI` at the first <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, and that the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is not used as date separator (which is very unlikely and uncommon):

```cmd
for %%I in ("C:\TEMP\test.txt") do set "AGE=%%~tI"
set "AGE=%AGE: =" & rem "%"
if "%AGE%"=="%DATE%" echo File has been modified today.
```

Comment: Your point is correct in a single environment, but I've stumbled upon this system while importing a bunch of batchfiles from Czechia to Belgium :-)

Comment: Do you remember how these date formats looked like?

Answer (score 0):

After quite some work, I've found a way to get everything up and running (based on Lotping's answer):

```
set Filename=F:\\DIR\\Filename.exe
for /f %%a in ('wmic datafile where "Name='!Filename!'" get "lastmodified"^|findstr [0-9]') do set Filename_DATE=%%a
echo Filename_DATE=!Filename_DATE!
set FilenameFinalDATE=!Filename_DATE:~0,8!
echo !FilenameFinalDATE!
```

(Beware, everything is important here (double slashes, double percentages, single and double quotes, ...))